# Where to find tempdb logs in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, logging

I'm currently using SQL Server 2014. In a stored procedure, I'm inserting data into a local temporary table (`#TestTemporaryTable`). I want to see the logs of data insertion into temp table, how can I fetch it from `tempdb`? And also, I want to know for how long these logs will exist?

Comment: What kind of log are you looking for? In any case, `tempdb` is *temporary*. That means it's cleared every time the server restarts. Local temporary tables are discarded as soon as the connection that created them closes

Comment: What do you mean by "logs"? `tempdb` is (by default) set to the Simple Recovery Model (and for good reason), which truncates the transaction log as soon as the transaction is commited/rolled back. You can't inspect the log files for data in the first place anyway (can you imagine the security concerns that would have?), but certainly the logs for `tempdb` will be lost as soon as the transaction completes.

Comment: I want to view the ones which gets logged when rows are inserted into temporary table

Comment: Logged where? If you have a custom logging tool, then you know what that is; we don't know.

Answer (score 0):

You can examine the log records with the undocumented [fn_dblog](https://www.bing.com/search?q=fn_dblog)

eg

```
SELECT * FROM tempdb.sys.fn_dblog(NULL, NULL)
```